# Using Nokogiri to iterate through style attributes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, styles, nokogiri

I have an image tag which is like this :

```
<img src="#{some_source}" class="required-image" style="cursor: default; height: 188px;">
```

And I use the following nokogiri code to get the image tag.

```
html_part.xpath('//img[@class="required-image"]').each do |inline|
   #do some manipulations with the image
   inline[:style]
end
```

inline[:style] gives me the entire style as a string. But in my case, I just want to obtain the value of the style attribute 'height'. So is it possible to iterate through style attributes using nokogiri? If so, please help me out. I want to do something like inline[:style][:height] and get the value of the height attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regexp to extract it

```
>> s = "cursor: default; height: 188px;"
=> "cursor: default; height: 188px;"
>> s.scan /height:\s(.*);/
=> [["188px"]]
```

Comment: I was thinking of using regexp. I thought there should be some way to do this with nokogiri itself. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think Nokogiri has any stylesheet parsing capabilities.

Comment: OK for now, regexp is working for fine now. DO keep me posted, if you find anything which we can do by using nokogiri itself

Comment: No, it's not possible to get Nokogiri to iterate through the value assigned to a parameter. That's not Nokogiri's purpose.

Once Nokogiri gives us access to the content of a parameter it's done its job. From that point it's up to us to interpret that content. The same is true of processing the content of `<script>` and `<style>` tags; What's inside them is outside Nokogiri's domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nokogiri-styles gem.

[NokgiriStyles lets you decompose inline CSS styling (the style attribute) in HTML elements so you don’t have to bother with regexes and such.](https://github.com/rdmre/nokogiri-styles)